# How can i display a deep nested objects in a table - AngularJs - Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

Hello Members from StackOverFlow, I'm new over here.

I have a problem with my application, I'm using AngularJs and I have a http service, and i showed it in my console log (I think it doesn't even matter but i hope you can understand me).

First Of All, I have an array of 5 objects.

First of All, It is just 1 object in the beginning(parent), but it's the parent and with its id, I called the 5 array of objects inside the main object(parent), but i need to called the 1000+ objects inside the main object and show 'em in html the name, in the application, the object has a name and id(properties).

PS: the 5 array of objects have 40 objects inside, and the 40 objects inside have above 120.
Controller.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller("controller", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.objects= [];
    var promise = $http.get("link1")
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return $http.get('link2', {
                params: {
                    Id: response.data[0].Id
                }
            })
        })
    .then(function (response2) {
        console.log(response2);
        $scope.objects= response2.data;
        return response2.data;
    })
})
```

my HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tr ng-repeat="get in objects">
  <td>{{x.Name}}</a></td>
           </tr>
      </table>
```

but I would like to show all the name's Objects ( just the properties), in my HTML i just showed the 5 array of objects, but that 5 array of objects have more objects inside, any advice?.

PS: the objects can be deleted or changed.

Any advice, at least for being in the right direction.

Comment: Too confusing reading about *"objects have objects"*. The way to ask is to show some sample data and what expected results are

Comment: Can you please share the whole json and clear the requirement.